# C# Recovering Database stuck in 'Restoring...'

Tags: c#, sql, restore, recovery

I am inserting a SQL Database Backup and Recovery section into my program. I have been using MSDN Examples (tryed another and it wouldnt work).
MSDN Page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx

I have got the Backup file working, and have tested the file in Management Studio.

But I am having trouble with the Recovery of the file.

The code seems to be working, but the database in SQL Server is stuck in "Restoring..."

```
            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Server sqlServer = new Server();

                Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();
                sqlRestore.NoRecovery = true;
                sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;

                BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(openFile.FileName, DeviceType.File);
                sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
                sqlRestore.Database = "firstRecoverTest";

                sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);

                //Add the recovered database into the Entity Table
                SqlCommand intoEntity = new SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT entityName FROM Entitys WHERE entityName = 'firstRecoveryTest') INSERT INTO Entitys VALUES ('firstRecoveryTest');", sqlConnection);                   
                sqlConnection.Open();
                intoEntity.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Database db = default(Database);
                db = sqlServer.Databases["firstRecoverTest"];
                db.RecoveryModel = (RecoveryModel)1;
                db.AutoClose = true;
                //db.Alter();

            }
```

In the example there is a db.Alter(); function, but that throws an error that says "Alter failed for Database 'firstRecoverTest'".

Please let me know your thoughts

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

After inserting the "ReplaceDatabase = true;" there was no change in the end result. 
Also stepping though the code line by line, shows that it is making it through.

The "db.Alter();" is just that placed at the end of the code (shown as comment). It is used in the creation of the backup and works without error.
InnerError shows this information when using db.Alter();

"ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state"

The interesting part is the SQL Log files. I am getting 3 Logs:

"Starting up database 'firstRecoverTest'."

"The database 'firstRecoverTest' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run."

"Database was restored: Database: firstRecoverTest, creation date(time): 2011/09/20(15:44:48), first LSN: 37:159:37, last LSN: 37:175:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=DISK: {'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\installer_backup'}). Informational message. No user action required."

However, when I do a normal recover using SQL Management Studio there is 2 more log entrys saying

"Starting up database '[databaseName]'."

"Restore is complete on database '[databaseName]'. The database is now available"

I don't have enough reputation to post a small image of how it is in SQL Management Studio unfortunatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try either dropping the database or using `sqlRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.replacedatabase.aspx

If it looks like nothing is happening you can start the process in a seperate thread and wire up the events for notification of progress changes by using these.

```
sqlRestore.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(completionEvent);
sqlRestore.PercentCompleteNotification = 10; // Call progress event every x percent change.
sqlRestore.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(progressEvent);
```

If that doesn't work can you please post the Alter code that wasn't working. Also check SQL server logs and permissions.

**UPDATED**

Ok that update makes more sense. The reason is because you are setting `sqlRestore.NoRecovery = true;`. This has the effect that after the restore is done the DB is kept in a recovery state so you can restore an additional differential backup in addition to the full you just restored.

While it is in this state you will not be able to do anything more to the database. I would suggest that unless you require it you leave the default which is `NoRecovery = false`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.norecovery.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have updated my post with information that can hopefully help explain what is happening

Comment: Thank you. 
I had thought that I had tried changing that over, but I must have had something else wrong that made it fail. This solved the problem.
Thank you again